# Google Analytics: Grouping similar referrals without loosing source

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, referrals

Lets say I have 100 customers that bought a website from me. In the footer of their websites I have the text "Website developed by:" followed by a link that points to my company website. In Google Analytics for my company website these referrals will show up with the customers URL as source, and "referral" as medium. I would like all of the referrals from my 100 customer websites to be grouped, so that i can view the total metrics together. I have tried using utm_source="Customer Website" on the referral links, but the utm_source overwrites the default source (that is the customer website URL) so that there is no way for me to separate the different websites.

How can I set up this in Google Analytics so that I can both view all of the referrals from customer websites together and separately?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `utm_campaign=Customer-Referral` and then see all this data under one campaign on Google Analytics.
2. You can direct the traffic to the destination page but with a dummy query string parameter such as `www.example.com?ref=client`, and then see the traffic that is directed to this specific page on Google Analytics.
3. Based on the ref, you can inject a user-level custom dimension that will show you data of that specific group. What you should add is `ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Client Referral');`
   Add it to your tracking code before `ga('send', 'pageview');` You need to send this data only once, at the first page view. You can read more about it here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets

(note: I used `dimension1` assuming that you don't have existing custom dimensions. If you already using slot no. 1, update it to another slot).

Comment: The problem is that utm_source and utm_medium are both required in a URL when you tag it. So i am not allowed to use only the utm_campaign. You can see it at Google own URL builder. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

Comment: Yeah that's true, but why can't you use the three of them?

Comment: Becuase as soon as i use the utm_source, the referrer gets overwritten by the value in utm_source. If the site "www.myreferralsite.com" is the referrer, and the link has utm_source="Customer Site", then there will be no trace of "www.myreferralsite.com" in analytics. It will be replaced by Customer Site. I'm looking at using utm_source="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" to keep the referring site URL. Is there any problems with this approach?

Comment: Can't you change them one by one? Might be a lengthy process but worth it. If you can't, you can indeed add the hostname dynamically (not to add php to the url of course). By the way, a custom dimension can also help. I will update my answer.

Comment: When you say "not to add php to the url of course" do you mean that i can NOT do it this way? http://www.mywebsite.com/?utm_source=<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=Customersite

Comment: I was afraid that you wanted by mistake to send PHP code as the request URI. If you wanted to generate this data dynamically on the page of your client, so it generated a valid URI, then it's ok.